# Auto Reloading Properties file

Tags: java, weblogic

I have a web based application which has few of its properties declared in a property file. I am using Weblogic to deploy this application. As expected, in case of any changes in the property files, we have to restart the weblogic server for the changes to take effect.

However, now there is a requirement where I am supposed to avoid the server restart incase of a change in any of the property files. I wonder whether it is possible at all, as I am not able to find any solution to it.

Kindly let me know is it at all possible. If yes, then how ?

Comment: are you loading the properties directly, or is weblogic reading the file?

Comment: Even we are planning to achieve this in our project. We are planning to persist the properties in DB and run a batch once a new properties file is uploaded which will replace the value of the the updated placeholders in the context. But we have not had much success yet.

Answer (score 1):

For property auto reloading you can use FileSysstemManager and VFS FileListener
Register file on startup with FileSystemManager for monitoring. Then on file change fileChanged would be invoked where property can be reloaded.

Eg code :

```
public class PropertyManager implements FileListener {

    @Override
    public void fileChanged(FileChangeEvent fileChangeEvent) {

        //Reload here into  memory
    }

}

private register(STring fileName) {

    String pathToPropertyFile = new ClassPathResource(fileName).getFile().getPath();
    FileSystemManager fsManager = VFS.getManager();
    FileObject listenFile = fsManager.resolveFile(pathToPropertyFile);

    DefaultFileMonitor fm = new DefaultFileMonitor(this);
    fm.setRecursive(true);
    fm.addFile(listenFile);
    fm.setDelay(15000);
    fm.start();

}
```